# How to convert HTML table into jQuery DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've tried this:

```
<html> <body>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/DataTables/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script> <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <table id="myTableId">
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Rows</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtRows"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Columns</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtCols"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="btnDisplay" value="Display" onClick="ShowTable();"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tbl_DynamicTable" border="1" style="display:none">
        </table>
    </body>         <script type="text/JavaScript">
                function ShowTable()        {
                    document.getElementById("tbl_DynamicTable").style.display = "";             createTable();      }
                function createTable()          {
                var rows = document.getElementById("txtRows").value;
                var cols = document.getElementById("txtCols").value;
                var table = document.getElementById("tbl_DynamicTable");
                var str="";

                var randomColor; 
                for(var i=0;i<rows;i++)
                {
                    randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                    str += "<tr id=row" + i +" bgcolor="+randomColor+">";

                    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++)
                    {
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            str += "<th> Header " + j + "</th>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str += "<td> Row " + i + ", Cell "+ j + "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    str += "</tr>";
                }
                table.innerHTML = str;
                $("#myTableId").dataTable();            }   </script>    </html>
```

I want to convert this table into jQuery DataTable.

It's showing error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined [repeated 2 times]`.

How to solve this? I want to use this jQuery DataTable to Searching and paging function. But first want to convert it into DataTable first.

Comment: When is your call executed? It seems you are declaring functions, when never calling them. Maybe you want this to be executed on ready?

Comment: Also this error makes me thing your jQuery is not included correctly. Check in the Network tab of your developer tools, see if the files are all loaded correctly

Comment: You are not linking `jquery` in your html

Comment: Cells will be executed on the Click of Display button. On click of `Display` button, `ShowTable` will be called.

Comment: I have tried the code and it's working!! [See this link](http://jsfiddle.net/p78WT/) what is the problem?

Comment: Done, thank you. Any solutions regarding to searching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for DataTables to be able to function correctly, the HTML for the target table must be laid out in a well formed manner with the 'thead' and 'tbody' sections declared. For example:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So to make it filterable do I need to add `<thead>` in `html` code?

Comment: table should follow above markup then initilaise the data table

Comment: But @Sridhar, I'm creating the whole table dynamically so, its not possible i guess...

Comment: its possible @PratikSoni try with 2 variables and loop through it

Answer (score 3):

Make the head and body of the table into separate sections (thead and tbody) and call the plugin.

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({
        // parameters
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**outside the function you declare otable.**

```
var oTable;
```

**Inside a function after create a html table:**

```
 if(oTable.length>0)
       oTable.fnDestroy();


    oTable=$("tableid").dataTable({
                    "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
                    "sScrollY":500,
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bSortClasses": false
                });
```